# JScrollPane issue when using % widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm just starting to use JScrollPane, which seems to work flawlessly with 1 exception. I am trying to use it in a scenario where % widths are needed, and despite everything initially seeming fine, the div does not stretch dynamically with the browser window. This only occurs once I've applied JScrollPane to the div.

Does anyone know how to fix this? As it is, the div does stretch like it should do once the page is loaded, but if the browser window is stretched thereafter the div does not stretch like it should do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little tinkering I was able to find a work-around to this problem. Simply refreshing the call to .jScrollPane(); on .resize() seems to work a charm. Tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE & Safari on Win7.

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```